# Should I use my own implementation or the stack class in java.util package?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, queue

In Java, I can implement my own `Stack` like below or use the already provided `java.util.Stack` class.

```
public class stack {

private int maxSize; //max size of stack
private char[] stackArray;
private int top; //index poistion of last element

public stack(int size){
    this.maxSize=size;

    this.stackArray=new char[maxSize];
    this.top=-1; //    
    }


public void push(char j){

    if (isFull()) {
        System.out.println("SORRY I CANT PUSH MORE");
    }else{

    top++;
    stackArray[top]=j;
        }
    }

public char pop(){

    if(isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Sorry I cant pop more!");
        return '0';
    }else{

       int oldTop=top;
       top--;
       return stackArray[oldTop];    
       }
    }


public char peek(){
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        return stackArray[top];
        }
    }


public boolean isEmpty(){
    return (top==-1);
    }

public boolean isFull(){
    return (maxSize-1 == top);
    }

} //end of stack class
```

The second way is to use the `Stack` class in Java API.

```
Stack<String> stacky = new Stack<>();
```

The same is the situation with `Queues` in Java.

Should I go with my own implementation when using `Stacks` or `Queues`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should never use your own implementation of something already in the Java Runtime Library, since that code has been tested way more than your code is likely to be tested.

Also, generally speaking, you should never use the legacy [`java.util.Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class, since it is `synchronized`. As the javadoc of `Stack` says:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by **the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface** and its implementations, which **should be used in preference to this class**. For example:
>
> ```
> Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
> ```

Anyway, for your question *"How many ways to implement a stack in java?"*, there are 5 stack implementations in the Java Runtime Library:

- [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) - legacy, not recommended
- [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) - generally best choice for single-threaded use
- [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) - generally best choice for multi-threaded use
- [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) - If you need stack with size limit
- [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) - If stack can grow big, and you want to reclaim space as it shrinks

And of course any [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation can be used as a stack, but without convenient methods, e.g. for [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) you'd want to use `list.add(list.size(), e)` to push element onto the "stack".

Answer (score 0):

In production code, you would always use the implementation available from the Java library. The only reason to implement it yourself is for educational purposes (learning about how data structures internals work).

Implementations that are part of Java (like `java.util.Stack`, `java.util.ArrayList`, etc.) are well-tested and known to work well, and they can easily be included in any project. Your own implementation, on the other hand, is much more likely to contain bugs, and the code will not be as portable since it may use non-standard functionality.